# How to Sort (or Get a List) of Files By Filename Endings

Tags: php, windows, list, sorting

Any way (or program) to sort or list files in a directory according to their filename endings?
I have multiple files in a directory, the file names have the following format:
"File A (3).ext"
"File B (1).ext"
"File C (2).ext"
I would like to list them like this:
"File B (1).ext"
"File C (2).ext"
"File A (3).ext"

Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide a comprehensive example. What language are you using (if any?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard library functions strrev and qsort will do it for you